# How to install multiple versions of the same software?

Tags: windows, installation

I manage phone systems for multiple clients. Each system uses the same administrator software, but it runs on different versions depending on what version of firmware is installed on the system controller.

The software is downloaded directly from the system controller so it's the right version. For example, if the controller runs on version 5.0.2, you have to run version 5.0.2 of the administrator software. You can't administrate a 5.0.2 controller with a later versions of administrator software.

Bottom line, you have to have the right version of software to log into the controller. The software is not executable on its own, you have to install it. So every time I want to log into a different controller, I have to reinstall the right software.

Any way to get around this?

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise x86.

Answer (score 8):

1. Install few version into different folders (if software allow it).
2. Install one by one (versions) and just copy folders with software to the some other place (if software does not allow to be installed into different folders).
3. Use Virtual machines with different versions of this software, but this is the hardest way.