# How to install multiple versions of YNAB 4 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, installation

I run **You Need A Budget classic (YNAB 4)** on Windows 10. (I know it is now [obsolete and no longer supported since replaced by the online version](https://www.youneedabudget.com/ynab-4-support-will-end-october-2019/), but it still works fine for me.) It only allows one version to run at a time, but I would like to run multiple versions so that I can open different budgets at the same time, which the standard software (based on [Adobe AIR](https://www.adobe.com/products/air.html)) does not permit. How can I do this?

I have already tried different generic solutions on Super User for opening multiple programs simultaneously, but none of them worked for me:

- [How to install multiple versions of the same software?](https://superuser.com/questions/404447/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-the-same-software)
- [How to install two versions of software under Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1146874/how-to-install-two-versions-of-software-under-windows-10)

Answer (score 3):

After fruitlessly trying many options (including the ones linked in the question above), here is what finally worked for me.

YNAB seems to be configured very spefically using the [Adobe AIR](https://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) platform. I don't understand how it works, but here is the hack that did the job for me:

- Note that you need administrative rights on the computer to do all the following, since you'll be messing with the Program Files folder.
- Copy and paste the entire folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\YNAB 4`. It will probably be automatically renamed something like "YNAB 4 - copy", since two subfolders in the same folder cannot have the same name.
- Optional: rename the folder `YNAB 4 - copy` to something you prefer; in my case, I renamed it `YNAB 4 - v2`.
- Open the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\YNAB 4 - v2\META-INF\AIR\application.xml`.
- Near the top of the file (Line 8 in my case), change the id in `<id>com.ynab.YNAB4.LiveCaptive</id>` to anything else that is unique. In my case, I changed it to `<id>com.ynab.YNAB4.LiveCaptive.v2</id>` (that is, I simply added `.v2` to the end.
- Save and close the file.
- Henceforth, you should be able to open the second version of YNAB by doubleclicking the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\YNAB 4 - v2\YNAB 4.exe`; you can create a shortcut to it if you like.